# Relationships between 4 models in Ruby On Rails - company, brand, group of products, product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm trying to work out correct relationships between models for a RoR app, and I need a little help. It seemed quite easy before I actually tried to put it to work.

I've got 4 models - Company which can have some Brands, then Brands can have Products. That's seem easy but ... Product will also belong to Group of Products - how does it fit in? And how to set the association between Brands and Group of Products.

I'm probably over-thinking it, but how to set those relationships correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modelling for Rails, also make sure if read the official [guide for Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Make sure you read and understand the [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) section.

The modelling of your data will be dependent of what you are going to use. It could make sense to build a complete normalized model or you can denormalize in order to increase performance.

If you want to keep the things simple use something like this:

Companies `has_many` Brands and Brands `belongs_to` Company

Brands `has_many` GroupOfProducts (you need to evaluate if two brands can have the same Group of products)

GroupsOfProducts `has_many` Products and Products `belongs_to` GroupsOfProducts

Comment: Hello Paulo, thanks for the answer, Brands would definately have more than one GroupOfProducts, and performance is not a major concern in that case, so complete normalized models would be perfect.